# How to find text after the closed element and delete it

Tags: xslt

I want to delete the element and the text which is found after the element.
Example :

> ```
>  <p>life</p>$
> ```

In the above example I want to replace

> ```
> <p>&nbsp;</p>$
> ```
>
> with " "(empty) or simply delete it.
>   Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete something from input XML, you should write an **emty template**
matching such nodes. The rest is copied by the *identity template*.

And as far as your task is concerned, I am in doubt whether you want to
delete **all** `p` elements.
So in my example script I wrote an empty template for `p` elements
with `class="xx"`.

To delete a **text node** following it (the `$` in your sample XML),
you have to write also an empty template, matching just such a node:

- a text node,
- which has the first preceding sibling with name `p` and `class="xx"`.

So the script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="p[@class='xx']"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p[@class='xx']]]"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the following input, including also some other `p` elements, but without
the specified class and text nodes following them:

```
<root>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p class="xx">life</p>$
  <p>is brutal</p>Xxx
  <p>and full of traps</p>Yyy
</root>
```

It gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>is brutal</p>Xxx
  <p>and full of traps</p>Yyy
</root>
```